# Arrangements of all the letters in the word "rearrangement" with the r's being adjacent

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

If an arrangement of all the letters in the word "rearrangement" is chosen at random, what is the probability that all the r's are adjacent? Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count up how many permutations there are with the $r$ characters adjacent. We group the $r$'s together as one cluster. This leaves us with $11$ characters to permute. We have two $a$'s, three $e$'s, and two $n$'s. So we have $$\dfrac{11!}{2! * 2! * 3!}$$

Now we count up the number of ways to permute all $13$ characters. Again, we use a multinomial distribution: $$\dfrac{13!}{2! * 2! * 3! * 3!}$$

Divide the first count grouping the three $r$'s together by the number of ways to permute the $13$ characters.